# rsvg doesn't render linked images

Tags: svg, librsvg

I use the python `rsvg` bindings to render an svg image into cairo and save to file, which mostly works. But if the svg file contains a linked image, like so:

```
<image href="static/usrimgs/tmpDtIKpx.png" x="10" y="10" width="600px" height="400px"></image>
```

the image doesn't show up in the final file (the rest of the svg renders just fine). The relative path is correct based on where the script is running, but I'm guessing there's some problem with the fact that it would normally be a relative URL, not a relative filepath. How do I get around this?

Comment: I have the same problem. Putting an invalid url href (link to a file that doesn't exists) reveals that rsvg wont output an error if it can't find the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was to process the links to start with `file:///` and be a full absolute path.

Comment: didn't help for me :(. It works on another machine with same librsvg version. Not on this archlinux machine, though. Even compiled rsvg-convert myself.. didn't help.

Comment: Same problem (using OSX 10.9)

Answer (score 17):

There are many factors which must be satisfied for LibRsvg to allow an image resource to be loaded. As of v2.40 these include:

- the image must have an `xlink:href` attribute
- that attribute must contain a full, valid URI
- the scheme can be `data://` or `file://`
- `file://` paths must be absolute
- `file://` paths must be in or below the path of the SVG source file (after any symlinks have been dereferenced)

Note that if input is passed to `rsvg-convert` via stdin, then no paths count as subdirectories of the input file and all `file://` images will be denied.

```
rsvg-convert < input.svg > output.png  # images denied

rsvg-convert -o output.png input.svg  # images allowed
```

The code governing image URL resolution can be found in the [LibRsvg source](http://download.gnome.org/sources/librsvg) in `rsvg-base.c`, function `_rsvg_handle_allow_load`.

To add a debugging notification to rsvg-convert when image loading fails, one can append

```
#define G_ENABLE_DEBUG
```

to `config.h` in the source and recompile.

Comment: To update this, the rules are now spelled out in the file allowed_url.rs, available here: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/librsvg/blob/master/rsvg_internals/src/allowed_url.rs

Answer (score 4):

It seems that, if the file you are including is not on the same path or under the path of the SVG file you want to convert, it will not find it.
I regard this as a bug.

Comment: A 'security feature' I guess. I looked at the source and there is no way to disable it short of a recompile. Just a note that this worked on Ubuntu 10.04, but on 12.04 this 'feature' was added.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to get librsvg image rendering working on my Mac to speed up SVG rendering. Ian Mackinnon's great answer has all the ingredients but implementing a change to the library is tricky. These steps made librsvg correctly render linked images with relative paths. I hope this saves someone some time.

First, I installed librsvg using:

```
brew install --build-from-source librsvg
```

At the time of writing, this installs version 2.40.13 and the necessary libraries to build it. I then downloaded and extracted the source archive into my home directory:

```
wget https://download.gnome.org/sources/librsvg/2.40/librsvg-2.40.13.tar.xz
tar jxvf librsvg-2.40.13.tar.xz
cd librsvg-2.40.13
```

I edited the `_rsvg_handle_allow_load` function in `rsvg-base.c` in this directory to bypass the path loading restrictions by adding this code around line 2275:

```
2275
2276     goto allow; // Just try and load it!
2277
```

I also needed to edit the `rsvg_cairo_surface_new_from_href` function in `rsvg-image.c` and stop it loading using mime types - just replace the function like this:

```
55     if (mime_type) {
56         // loader = gdk_pixbuf_loader_new_with_mime_type (mime_type, error);     // This doesn't work on my mac
57         loader = gdk_pixbuf_loader_new (); // This works
58     } else {
59         loader = gdk_pixbuf_loader_new ();
60     }
```

I needed to use these slightly modified commands to compile and install the modified library:

```
make clean
make install gdk_pixbuf_binarydir=/usr/local/Cellar/librsvg/2.40.13/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders gdk_pixbuf_moduledir=/usr/local/Cellar/librsvg/2.40.13/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders
```

Depending on your system, you might need to add sudo to the above commands.

Once this was done, I could render relative SVG links using the `rsvg-convert` command line tool that is installed with librsvg:

```
rsvg-convert test.svg -o test.png
```

I was also able to use ImageMagick to convert SVGs with relative image links to PNG files if I installed it after installing librsvg in this way:

```
convert test.svg test.png
```

This will let you test rsvg function and performance - I found it was 2-3x faster than Inkscape for my application. I recommend changing the code more intelligently if you use this in a production environment.