# svg to png is not working in php

Tags: php, svg, imagick

I am using the imagick to convert svg to png. But my svg contain embedded images in it. so while converting it to png does not render the embedded image.

```
$image = new \Imagick();
try{
    $file_name = uniqid($prefix).".jpeg";
    $image->readImageBlob($raw_svg);
    $image->setImageFormat("png24");
    $image->writeImage("$folder_name/".$file_name);
} catch (ImagickException $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

## SVG Data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="600" height="400" viewBox="0 0 600 400" xml:space="preserve">
<desc>Created with Fabric.js 2.0.0-beta7</desc>
<defs>
</defs>
<rect x="0" y="0" width="600" height="400" fill="#000000"></rect>
    <g transform="translate(300.77 141.27) scale(2.45 2.26)">
        <text xml:space="preserve" font-family="Dollar2" font-size="22" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(255,255,255); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1; white-space: pre;" >
            <tspan x="-117.34" y="6.91" >Back Side</tspan>
        </text>
    </g>
<g transform="translate(289.57 247.98) scale(0.35 0.35)">
    <image xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANtTyE2NP5d9xZHM0bHtWwv3UYAuCINIplLWR8DS0uSOiTGLf1D2r/s3a8rxSbGLsVX4jt7nWc7JwHa/hqcyfVf6ZPmZ/u79nun+mTHHP6VX+t6lO+PckRyonYcOdqNETPJtLnBs89dwI0s7Y24alIM0g883zrzOP61/GnsT/6p607++djHcyJo6rcpFOQRCyjv8TYAAeI+bBrle9xgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" x="-334.5" y="-173.5" style="stroke: rgb(240,240,240); stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-opacity: 0; fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" width="669" height="347"></image>
<rect x="-334.5" y="-173.5" width="669" height="347" style="stroke: rgb(240,240,240); stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: none; fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

[image: SVG Image SS]
[image: PNG IMAGE SS]

Comment: let me know if any thing is missing, i have tried to include most of the details.

Comment: The image data posted seem to be corrupt.

Comment: For security, many SVG delegates will not render `image xlink` tags. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29632564/438117) for tips.

Comment: @ccprog Yes, the question box doesn't allowed me to post all raw data because of limit around 30,000 or something.

Comment: Doesn't make it easier to find out what is happening. Use a CodePen? Do you have either Inkscape or librsvg intalled in your system? (Both are used as rendering backends by ImageMagick.)

Comment: @ccprog here's the url: https://codepen.io/dhavalsisodiya/pen/XewGey

Comment: i have (MSVG  SVG       rw+   ImageMagick's own SVG internal renderer),
      (SVG  SVG       rw+   Scalable Vector Graphics (XML 2.9.1)), 
     SVGZ  SVG       rw+   Compressed Scalable Vector Graphics (XML 2.9.1)

Comment: Still not sure. I was working from the assumption the internal renderer was not able to cope with the file. But for me (v6.9.9 on windows) it renders the embeded image (albeit with that faint white outline also shown in you screenshot). Your best bet might nonetheless be to install librsvg which surely is superior to MSVG.

Comment: Please can you try with different php versions? What I know is that imagick compiled for php 5.6 can have issues when used with php 7.0, or vice versa. I can give a full answer if this comment helps.

Answer (score 0):

Above is get resolved after changing the below:
php version: 5.5

> apt-get install php5-imagick
>   apt-get install graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat
>   apt-get install imagemagick
>   apt-get install build-essential checkinstall && apt-get build-dep imagemagick -y

To add custom fonts:
copy all custom font(ttf file) to below location:

> /usr/share/fonts/truetype

then

> fc-cache -v /usr/share/fonts